# youtube-dl : backup channel as all videos + playlist for players

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I wonder if there is an option(s) of using [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) or [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) for backing up educational channels from youtube, in a way that will do the following (as a PS  or cmd script):

- create folder "videos" in the same folder as script is located
- download all videos from the channel to "videos" folder
- create folder "playlist"
- parse the created playlists of the same channel
- create the playlist file per each playlist (let say M3U file) out of already downloaded files from "videos" folder

The reason, why I don't want to use direct downloads as individual folders with videos per playlist, is that some playlists share the videos, and it would take more space on HDD.